# time exceed in PHP ? Want to increase time?

Tags: php, web-scraping, web-crawler, simple-html-dom, max-execution-timeout

I am trying to parsing HTML data from HTML file. I have a file which contains many links . I get those links and load them in file_get_contents($link) (I use simple_html_dom for all This stuff ) and want to find specific text in those link . It works great for three or five links after than I got fatal error: time exceeded 30 seconds in simple HTML Dom line 82 .

What are the problem I guessed ?
Slow internet speed (that I can not increase) .
PHP.INI file configuration
Simplehtmldom configuration

What I tried but failed ?

> I have edited max_execution_time to 0 and 300 but not worked after restart server (using local XAMPP server )
>
> I also tried to edit simple_HTML_Dom.PHP but did not worked .
>
> I do not know whether my server setting safe mode is  on or not

Thank you ,
Actually we are group of college student trying to make a project.

Comment: Determine if the request or parsing the HTML takes too long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know you tried setting `max_execution_time`, but you can try setting it using `ini_set` directly in your PHP script:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);
```

Also try `default_socket_timeout`, this will change the default timeout of the `file_get_contents` function:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 300);
```

Comment: Thank you Fransico Huppe for helping us. We just want to ask that setting PHP.INI and ini_set different ?

Comment: not really, ini_set is use when you want to change a config for a particular script only, but if you change it in PHP.INI and the server is properly restarted, it has the same effect

Answer (score 0):

Making max_execution_time to 0 in PHP.ini is a bad idea this is because timeouts are essential for webserver. However, in order to facilitate long time consuming script, you  may use  ini_set('max_execution_time', 0) which temporarily sets the value for max_execution_time.

Having put the value in script, keeps the new value during the script's execution, and will be restored at the script's ending.